# How to style (CSS) the HTML body of an email, created by an Android application (Intent)?

Tags: android, html, css, email, kotlin

The HTML body of an email opened/created from my Android application does not show any styling (CSS). Is there any way to make the CSS appear?

Firstly; I've tried adding a complete HTML template as well as just one html tag (H1). None of those show the CSS as expected.

Secondly; I've tried putting the CSS inline as well as in the style tag in the head section of my HTML document. Again, without any succes.

Note: The Kotlin code I provided opens the email client (Outlook) correctly and show the HTML code. However, it seems no styling has been added.

```
// Kotlin code
// Send email function
fun sendEmail(activity: Activity, TO: Array<String>?, CC: Array<String>?, Subject: String, ContentText: String?, ContentHtml: String?) {

    Log.i("Sending email", "")

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Subject)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ContentText)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, ContentHtml)

    try {
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."))
        //finish()
        Log.i("Finished sending email.", "")
    } catch (ex: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

// Calling the function with some values
val TO = null 
val CC = null
val Subject = "Your subject"
val ContentText = "Email message goes here" 
val ContentHtml = "<h1 style=\"color:red; margin: 15px;\">Hello World</h1>"
sendEmail(this@MainActivity, TO, CC, Subject, ContentText, ContentHtml)
```

While using the code above I received a black h1 header in my email. No styling has been added. Is there any way to make the styling/CSS visible in emails created from Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write your `ContentHtml` part inside ` (tilde) instead of double quotes " "?  May be this will help.

Comment: Assuming you meant using single quotes: Single quotes ('') denote (or encapsulate) a single character, whereas double quotes ("") are used for a string of characters. Thereby, when you try to do this in Kotlin, Android studio gives the error: Too many characters in character literal.